# Exclude index of tables, figures and contents from "titleformat" style

Tags: sectioning, formatting

Good afternoon.

Considering the following code, which modifies the headings style:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}


\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}


\titleformat%
{\chapter}[hang]%
{\bfseries}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}  
\vspace{0pt}% do not remove
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[
outer sep=0pt,
text width=2.5cm,
minimum height=2.5cm,
fill=black,
font=\color{white}\fontsize{80}{90}\selectfont,
align=center
] (num) {\thechapter};
\node[
outer sep=0pt,
inner sep=0pt,
anchor=south,
font=\color{black}\Large\normalfont
] at ([yshift=8pt]num.north) {\textls[180]{\textsc{\chaptertitlename}}};
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{minipage}%
}
{0pt}%
{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.7\linewidth}%
    \vspace{22pt} % do not remove
    \rule{\linewidth}{2.5pt}\\\vskip -1.75\baselineskip%
    \rule{\linewidth}{.7pt}\vskip 5pt
    {\LARGE\raggedright\textsf{#1}}
\end{minipage}%
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]%
}


\begin{document}
    \chapter{The Singular Sturm-Liouville Problems in Spectral Parameter}
\end{document}
```

I'm attempting to exclude the following sections from this format: **list of figures**, **list of tables** and **index of contents**. In other words, I would like to have the default 'plain' style on those 3 sections (so that it doesn't apply the code above on those). Would it be possible to modify the titleformat code so it only applies to the chapters themselves and not to the aforementioned sections?

Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: Make another `\titleformat` with the `numberless` key.

Comment: Hi, @Bernard, thank you very much for your comment! Could it something in the lines of: \titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[hang]
  {\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\hspace{-0.4pt}\Large}   ? I tried that, but it makes no difference whatsoever: the other titleformat somehow prevails.

Comment: That's strange. Normally, you don't have the tikzpicture. Table of contents, bibliography, lists of figures or tables are  unnumbered chapters.  Could you post s small compilable code  reproducing your problem? Also, did you compile twice after this modification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: a]

Your code with some corrections.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}  

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}   

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]% <<<<<<
{\bfseries}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}  
        \vspace{0pt}% do not remove
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[
            outer sep=0pt,
            text width=2.5cm,
            minimum height=2.5cm,
            fill=black,
            font=\color{white}\fontsize{80}{90}\selectfont,
            align=center
            ] (num) {\thechapter};
            \node[
            outer sep=0pt,
            inner sep=0pt,
            anchor=south,
            font=\color{black}\Large\normalfont
            ] at ([yshift=8pt]num.north) {\textls[180]{\textsc{\chaptertitlename}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}  
    \end{minipage}%
}
{0pt}%
{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.7\linewidth}%
        \vspace{2pt} % do not remove
        \rule{\linewidth}{2.5pt}\\\vskip -1.75\baselineskip%
        \rule{\linewidth}{.7pt}\vskip 5pt
        {\LARGE\raggedright\textsf{#1}}
    \end{minipage}% 
}
    
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[hang] % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
{\sffamily\bfseries\LARGE\raggedright}
{}
{0pt}
{#1}    
    
    
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents    
    
    \chapter{The Singular Sturm-Liouville Problems in Spectral Parameter}       
    
\end{document}
```